# Problem my app starts in the second activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, onclick

I summarize ...
Previously I was looking for help to solve a problem with my secondary activity which did not process the Onclick, after receiving the help I got another error!
It turns out that now my application starts but in the second activity
it won't let me leave the app or handle it
I don't know what the error is
Fact: Surely it is simple, I comment that I am new to android programming :)!
Images:
Previous code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huZLu.png Error code
Previus all code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJYJ.png

Code after the solution, that is, my new error (My app starts in the emulator with the second activity and not with the first)

Images:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cwzc.png Provided solution and possible problem

```
if (mPaginaActiva.IsFinal()) {
            mOpcion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mOpcion2.setText("INTENTARLO DE NUEVO");
            mOpcion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1D2i.png All code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secundario);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mNombre = intent.getStringExtra("Nombre");
        mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ContenidoImageView);
        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ContenidoTextView);
        mOpcion1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.opcionButton1);
        mOpcion2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.opcionButton2);

        loadpage(0);



    }

    private void loadpage(int i) {
        mPaginaActiva = mContenidos.getPage(i);
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(mPaginaActiva.getImageId());
        mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        String pageText = mPaginaActiva.getText();
        pageText = String.format(pageText, mNombre);

        mTextView.setText(pageText);

        if (mPaginaActiva.IsFinal()) {
            mOpcion1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mOpcion2.setText("INTENTARLO DE NUEVO");
            mOpcion2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });


        } else {

        mOpcion1.setText(mPaginaActiva.getOpcion1().getText());
        mOpcion2.setText(mPaginaActiva.getOpcion2().getText());

        mOpcion1.setOnClickListener( (v) -> {
        int nextPage = mPaginaActiva.getOpcion1().getNextPage();
        loadpage(nextPage);
            }) ;

        mOpcion2.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            int nextPage = mPaginaActiva.getOpcion2().getNextPage();
            loadpage(nextPage);

        });
    }


}}
```

Hope this can be solved!
The other solution gave me the method but it gave me this problem, my app stays checked in the second activity.java and not in the first as it should start :(
sorry if it's completely easy :)!

Code MainActivity 1 (The activity where the app should start (Activity 1))

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mCampoNombre;
    private Button mBotonInicio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mCampoNombre = findViewById(R.id.NombreEditText);
        mBotonInicio = findViewById(R.id.InicioButton);

        mBotonInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               String nombre = mCampoNombre.getText().toString();
               startStory(nombre);
            }
        });


    }

    private void startStory(String nombre) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecundarioActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Nombre", nombre);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say u have 2 activity's; a **login activity** and the **main activity**. If u want your app to start at the **login activity** go to your **AndroidManifest.xml** and add these line of code under the right activity:

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So it should look like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: I checked it and that code is fine, I don't understand why it starts the second activity and not the first :(

Comment: I just tried it on an external device. It started with the first activity! But when entering data in the login and touching the button it stops :(

Comment: @Dannogger how are u starting the next activity on click of the button?